# Cannot find module error while running cypress test using saucectl

Tags: cypress, saucelabs

While trying to run cypress test from saucectl (saucelab) I am getting "Error: Cannot find module 'pdf-parse'". Not sure how to resolve this issue as my test works fine while running locally. Let me know if anyone has any solution for this.

index.js file path: \cypress\plugins\index.js
pdf require detail: const pdfparser = require("pdf-parse");

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have a dependency in your tests that is not installed on the Sauce Labs VM.
Please check all dependencies you use in your tests and add them to you config yaml-file as described [here](https://docs.saucelabs.com/web-apps/automated-testing/cypress/yaml/#npm)

It would look something like this

```
npm:
  packages:
    pdf-parse: "1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to install the npm dependency,

```
npm i pdf-parse
```

Comment: +@Pali solution from @wswebcreation worked for me. The error was from saucectl side as I have not added dependency in config.yml file.